# What's the difference between ipfs.infura.io vs ipfs.io

Tags: infura, ipfs

When saving ipfs hash, i find that `ipfs.infura.io` is x10 faster than `ipfs.io`.
If the public gateway (`ipfs.io`) has a negative impact on user experience due to its slowness, why people would use that endpoint instead of using `ipfs.infura.io`? Any cons of using `ipfs.infura.io/hash`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you going about saving the ipfs hash? that could depend on whether or not infura or ipfs public gateway is faster.

Generally speaking though, as talked about at IPFS Camp, the ipfs network has grown from like 8k peers to 300k in the last 3-4 months. Subsequently, the amount of traffic going to ipfs.io and all the infrastructure protocol labs are running has skyrocketed, and their infrastructure has basically been massively overwhelmed.

As for possible cons, you're just using a public gateway so use whatever is fastest and available.